# How to define Twitter application permissions

Tags: twitter, spring-social

With Facebook, you could set a scope parameter to define the permission you'd like a user to grant to the 3rd party application, according to the [Spring Social](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#authorization-scope) document. For example, you could only give the permission that the 3rd party can just read the user's profile, or you could give the permission that the 3rd party can post onto the user's wall too.

But with Twitter, how to set a scope-like parameter so as to define the permission you'd like a user to give to the 3rd party application? For example, the 3rd party can not only read the user's profile, but also tweet on behalf the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scoped permissions, such as what Facebook offers, is defined in the OAuth 2 specification. Twitter, on the other hand, is primarily an OAuth 1.0a-secured API (although it does offer OAuth 2-style app-only tokens) and OAuth 1.0a does not have the notion of scoped permissions.

That said, Twitter itself does define 3 levels of permissions: Read-only, read-write, and direct messages. These are not scopes that can be requested at authorization time, however. They are application-level, set when you register your application with Twitter.

Since Twitter doesn't offer scoped permissions, there's no way that Spring Social can offer it when authorizing with Twitter.

See https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/application-permission-model for more details on Twitter's application permission model.

Comment: Thanks Craig. Yes, when logged in to https://apps.twitter.com, and enter into the settings of a Twitter application, then in the Permissions panel, I can see the three options you mentioned: (1) Read only, (2) Read and (3) Write, and  Read, Write and Access direct messages.